# Swfit 4: How can I get Optional<X> to print a description that includes `Optional`

Tags: swift, swift4

I am aware that optional values "under-the-hood" are represented as an `Optional` enum...

`public enum Optional<Wrapped> {
    case none
    case some(Wrapped)
}`

To some extent, this is hidden from developers (for good reason) and thus when printing optionals the default behaviour (in Swift 4) is to omit the `Optional` part and simply print either `nil` or the value alone.

```
let longFormDefinedOptionalInt: Optional<Int> = nil
let shortFormDefinedOptionalInt: Int? = 99

print("\(longFormDefinedOptionalInt)") // Prints "nil" and NOT "Optional.none"
print("\(longFormDefinedOptionalInt)") // Prints "99" and NOT "Optional.some(99)"
```

Is there anyway get at the full and true description of an optional, i.e. either "Optional.none" or "Optional.some(99)"

I am sure this is possible because XCTest does it somehow when printing failure messages, for example...

`XCTAssertEqual(Int("99"), 11)`

> XCTAssertEqual failed: ("Optional(99)") is not equal to ("Optional(11)")

Comment: The message from XCTest is not exactly what you want. You want `Optional.some(11)` while the message is just `Optional(11)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think XCTest uses the [`debugDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539924-debugdescription):

```
let a: Int? = 1
print(a.debugDescription) // Optional(1)
```

However, with `nil` values, this property will return `"nil"` instead of `"Optional.none"`.

You can write an extension:

```
extension Optional {
    var fullDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .none:
            return "Optional.none"
        case .some(let value):
            return "Optional.some(\(value))"
        }
    }
}

let a: Int? = nil
print(a.fullDescription)
```

Comment: What an idiot I did try `debugDescription` before posting, but I must've tried it with nil value and assumed it didn't work.  Thank you.

Comment: @OliverPearmain If you want to see `Optional.some` and `Optional.none` you still need to write an extension though.